# Change in Entropy after mixing of liquids

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

> A well-insulated container of negligible thermal capacity contains 30 kg of water at 90°C. A
>   mixing process then takes place in which 50 kg of liquid water at 17°C is added to the tank. The
>   mixing process is continued until thermal equilibrium is established. Determine:
>
> a) The final temperature of the mixture.
>
> b) The change in entropy of the water as a result of the mixing process.
>   (For liquid water, take cp = 4.18 kJ/kgK)

I've worked out that the temp at equilibrium is 317K. I'm having some difficulty working out the change in entropy. The answer is 2.01kJ/K. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Show us what you case up with so far please.